# Is there a better way to add objects to an ArrayList in java? Everytime i try to add or set something new it changes the whole array to that object

Tags: java, arraylist

I am making a card game and attempting to use a Card object made up of two string elements: the value of the card and the suit, and creating an ArrayList of these card objects. I have attempted this with the code below and have noticed that everytime i add a new element, i see that every element is changed to have the same data as the most recently added element
Here's my code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class testArrayList
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ArrayList<Card> deck= new ArrayList<Card>();

        String cValues[] = {"Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};
        int cVLength= cValues.length;
        String cSuit[] = {"Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"};
        int cSLength= cSuit.length;
        for(int k=0; k<cVLength; k++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<cSLength; j++)
            {
                deck.add(new Card(cValues[k],cSuit[j]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(deck.get(0).getValue()+ " "+ deck.get(0).getSuit());
        System.out.println(deck.get(1).getValue()+ " "+ deck.get(1).getSuit());
        System.out.println(deck.get(50).getValue()+ " "+ deck.get(50).getSuit());
        System.out.println(deck.get(51).getValue()+ " "+ deck.get(51).getSuit());
    }

}
class Card
{
    private static String value;
    private static String suit;
    public Card(String v, String s)
    {
        value   = v;
        suit    = s;
    }
    public static String getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }
    public static String getSuit()
    {
        return suit;
    }
}
```

please help anything is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems not your `ArrayList`, the problem's you `Card` class...

```
private static String value;
private static String suit;
```

Basically means that whatever value you set it to, it will change for EVERY instance of `Card`

Remove the `static` declarations, for example

```
class Card {

    private String value;
    private String suit;

    public Card(String v, String s) {
        value = v;
        suit = s;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public String getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }

}
```

When running it with your example, it now outputs...

```
Ace Hearts
Ace Diamonds
King Clubs
King Spades
```

Answer (score 2):

Your class `Card` has a fatal flaw, it only has static fields.

```
class Card
{
  private String value; // <-- not static
  private String suit;  // <-- not static
  public Card(String v, String s)
  {
    this.value   = v;   // <-- really not static.
    this.suit    = s;
  }
  public String getValue() // <-- also not static.
  {
    return value;
  }
  public String getSuit()
  {
    return suit;
  }
}
```